# How can I put excel data to choices field?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna put data in model by parsing excel.
models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    man = models.BooleanField()
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'manager'),
        ('l', 'leader'),
        ('o', 'others'),
    )
    employee =models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

  book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
  sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

  for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)  

  def build_employee(employee):
    if employee == 'leader':
      return 'l'
    if employee == 'manager':
      return 'm'
    if employee == 'others':
      return 'o'

for row in rows:
        is_man = row[4] != ""
        emp = build_employee(rows[5])
        user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3],   
        man=is_man,employee=emp)
        user.save()
```

Now I cannot understand how I should put data to employee variable.
Excel is like
[image]

I wanna put m or l or o to employee model, but I cannot understand how to be able to done so by using choices field.Or am I wrong to use choices field to achieve my goal?

Comment: Here is an error:
`for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)` should be 
`rows = list()
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows.append(sheet.row_values(row_index))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add function, what will be returned, employee variable that is ready to paste in DB. Like this:

```
def build_employee(employee):
    if employee == 'leader':
        return 'l'
    if employee == 'manager':
        return 'm'
    if employee == 'others':
        return 'o'
```

And call it in your method:

```
for row in rows:
        is_man = row[4] != ""
        emp = build_employee(row[4])
        user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3],   
        man=is_man,employee=emp)
        user.save()
```

Comment: thx, ur comments.I wrote ur codes, but error happens,
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'o'.

Comment: can you paste traceback?

Comment: Traceback is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 40, in <module>
    emp = build_employee(rows[4])
  File "/Users/XXX/testap/app/views.py", line 22, in build_employee
    return User.o
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'o'

Comment: How can I do it?I little bit changed views.py ,so I updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer. But try to make it in standard Django way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

Comment: Which parts did u change ur answer?I could not find changed points.

Comment: `return 'l'` and other returns

Comment: I cannot find ur answer's difference.Before,return 'l' was in ur code...

Comment: please tell me more strictly

Comment: all my code in `build_employee` is the same, I just replaced `return User.o` on `return 'o'`. All that you should do is replacing function build_employee

Comment: I replaced my codes, but error happens
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'manager'

Comment: Can you paste here a single item from rows? Just make `print(row)` in loop